# Squaring a floor value

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I know this is a very crude question and will receive down votes but my question still remains:

Is it true that
$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor^2 = \lfloor{x^2}\rfloor$$

Or generalising it to any arbitrary power $k$:
$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor^k = \lfloor{x^k}\rfloor$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint:  try some examples.  What about $x=1.5$ say?

Comment: @lulu wow. That gave me some insight.. Should've thought about this :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : take $$x=\sqrt2+1$$ now see
$$\lfloor x^2 \rfloor=\lfloor (\sqrt2+1)^2\rfloor =\\
\lfloor (2+2\sqrt2+1)\rfloor =\\3+\lfloor (2\sqrt2)\rfloor =5\\$$ vs
$$(\lfloor x \rfloor)^2=\\
(\lfloor \sqrt2+1 \rfloor)^2=\\2^2=4$$ so 
$$\lfloor x^2 \rfloor \neq (\lfloor x \rfloor)^2$$it is better to say 
$$\lfloor x^2 \rfloor \geq (\lfloor x \rfloor)^2$$

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for answer... I should have realised on my own. I'm tempted to say that the end result can be generalised to any power, ie, $\lfloor x^k \rfloor \geq (\lfloor x \rfloor)^k$, for any real $k$. Is it true?

Comment: @MihirChaturvedi :for $k=2n $ it is true  ,but not always true for odd $k $

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might want to try this by doing the following:

Let $x=n+r$ where $[x]=n$ and $0\leq\ r <1$. Then

$[x^2]=[(n+r)^2]=[n^2+2nr+r^2]=n^2+[2nr+r^2]$.

And $[x]^2=n^2$.

Equating both expressions we obtain $n^2=n^2+[2nr+r^2]$ which implies that $[2nr+r^2]=0$.
If $[2nr+r^2]=0$ then $0\leq\ 2nr+r^2<1$ so $0\leq\ 2[x]r+r^2<1$.

I really hope that this helps you! Can you work it from here? :-)